# Error: write EPIPE nodejs on centos server

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, centos, centos7

I have a problem with npm work on my centos server.

> error in ./resources/assets/sass/images/promo.jpg
>   Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14)
>
> ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/frontend.scss
>   Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14)
>       at runLoaders
>    (/var/www/html/alteca.ru/shared/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at /var/www/html/site.ru/shared/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at /var/www/html/site.ru/shared/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (/var/www/html/site.ru/shared/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at /var/www/html/alteca.ru/shared/node_modules/img-loader/index.js:45:31
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>    @ ./resources/assets/sass/frontend.scss
>    @ multi ./resources/assets/js/backend.js ./resources/assets/sass/backend.scss ./resources/assets/sass/frontend.scss

Centos - `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`
NodeJs - `6.11.3`
NPM - `3.10.10`
php framework - `laravel 5.5`

The problem is connected with jpeg files( Other files compiled correctly). But anyway I have no ideas how to solve it.

Does anyone know how to solve it?